# Understanding constructor.new

Tags: javascript

I think recently I've gotten a pretty good grasp of how objects are created and with prototypes. For example consider the following which I made

```
function Car(name) {

    this.name = name;
}

Car.prototype.color = "red";
Car.prototype.log = function() {
    return console.log("The car is: " + this.color + "with name" + this.name);
};
var carOne = new Car("honda");
console.log(carOne.log());
```

We can even display the constructor of our car like

```
function Car(name) {

    this.name = name;

}

var theCar = new Car('hyundai');
console.log('The new car constructor is' theCar.constructor);
```

But after reading some other people's code I've seen things like `new obj.constructor()`. What is this?

Comment: Your last `console.log()` is likely missing a `+`.

Comment: `obj.constructor` points to the constructor function which this object was instantiated with. You can dynamically create new instances without even knowing the constructor function itself.

Comment: It seems you know what a "constructor" is and what `new` does. This is pretty weird that you can't understand what that code snippet does.

Answer (score 2):

The `new` operator can be used with any "ordinary" function (but not ES2015 "arrow" functions). Thus if you have an object with a property whose value is a function reference, you can use it to construct an object. That's all it means; there's nothing magic or special about it.

When you construct an object instance via a constructor function, the instance will be initialized by the JavaScript runtime with a property named "constructor". That property will reference the function used to construct it. If you want another object of the same type, therefore, you can use that reference to create it.

Comment: You can't use `new` with arrow functions, or with most of the host-supplied ones. Really, only those meant as such or created by the `function` keyword count.

Comment: @JanDvorak oh right, that's a really good point. Thanks.

Comment: I see. Do you have an example of how I can tie it inside the code I presented. I think I would understand well like that

Comment: @cresjoy I'm not sure what you mean; what do you want to use it for? I mean, what do you want the code to do?

Comment: Suppose I do var obj = new Car.constructor('ferrari'). What does that mean?

Comment: if i console.log(obj) it gives me an anonymous function with ferrari in it. Why is that?

Comment: wait, you want to look for the `constructor` property on *instances* of Car, not on the constructor function itself.

Comment: I'm just confused as to when I would want to do something like obj.constructor.new. it seems like the code I have so far can do everything. I can even change the constructor directly when I do new Car("ferrari")

Comment: You'd do it when you had an object that came from somehere, and you know that you want to create another object from the same constructor, but you don't know exactly what the constructor function is already. I think that's a pretty unusual situation, to be honest - I write JavaScript all day and have done so for a bit over 10 years and I have never been in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

`obj.constructor` points to the constructor function which `obj` was instantiated with using the `new` keyword. You can dynamically create new instances without even knowing the constructor function itself. Thus the following are the same.

```
var a = new Car();
var b = new a.constructor();
```

Comment: So we with new a.constructor(), we can change the name of the car more easily? How is that useful

Comment: @cresjoy there are other use cases too. For example you check if an object is a Generator instance by `obj.constructor === GeneratorFunction` or check if an object is an Array `obj.constructor === Array`. 
I can see it has more usage as a pointer to the constructor function. Using it along with the `new` keyword is just one possible use case.

Comment: You can find a great overview here: http://www.2ality.com/2011/06/constructor-property.html